# Display pairs in Random order

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I randomised the order of pairs?
e.g. I have 3 elements stored in list e.g. A,B,C --> which makes pairs of A-B, A-C, B-C.

How can I display the pair in Random order?
e.g. 
A-B, A-C, B-C **or** B-C, A-B, A-C **or** A-C, A-B,B-C

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
  s.add("A");
  s.add("B");
  s.add("C");

ListGenerator lg = new ListGenerator(s);
```

OTHER CLASS

```
public class ListGenerator {

  private ArrayList<String> pairsX= new ArrayList<String>();

  public ListGenerator(ArrayList<String> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    int count_pairs = 0;

    // create a list of all possible combinations
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
       String s1 = ""+i;
       for(int j = (i+1) ; j < size ; j++)
       {
          count_pairs++;
          String s2 = ""+j;
          pairsX.add(s1+","+s2);
       }
    }

    System.out.println("numPairs "+count_pairs);
    for(String s : pairsX) {
       System.out.println(s);
    }
   }
```

Comment: You should really title the question with something closer to your main goal.  This is not a question about generating pairs but about randomly displaying arrays.  Took me a while after reading @SingleShot's brilliant one-liner to realize that he had answered the question you'd actually asked.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to change the title of my question. Yeah single shot is brilliant :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Collections.shuffle(pairsX);
```

Comment: I looked to see if all your answers were neat little one liners, as I had hoped from your name. Oh well. Nicely done.

Comment: Thanks, SingleShot. I forgot, I have used collections.suffle before but that is for single number. Thanks :-)

Comment: Ha ha. My name is from my online first-person shooter days :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am just providing you the pseudo code. Say you have three items in the list.

1. i= Generate a random number between 0 to list.size() -1
2. j =Generate another random number similarly.
3. Then print
   list.get(i)+"-"+list.get(j)

You can do this in a loop and add conditions to verify if the pair thus generated is a duplicate one.

I am assuming you know how to generate a random number between certain numbers..

You can do something like  (Math.random() * 1000)%3